# Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace on Service?

Tags: php, class, symfony, service

if a access the index login page I get this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1729:
Attempted to load class "LoginListener" from namespace "Chris\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

I wonder what the error comes from. I never implemented a syfmfony2 service.

Here are my sources:

my config.yml

```
login_listener:
    class: 'Chris\UserBundle\LoginListener'
    arguments: ['@security.context', '@doctrine']
    tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

my Chris/UserBundle/Controller/LoginListener.php

```
  <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: christian
 * Date: 22.07.15
 * Time: 11:38
 */

namespace Chris\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.1.0+
// use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.0.x
/**
 * Custom login listener.
 */
/**
 * @Route("blub", name="blub")
 */
class LoginListener
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em              = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Do the magic.
     *
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $userId = 1217;
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($userId);
            $user->setLetzterLogin(new \DateTime("now"));
            $em->flush();
        }

        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            // user has logged in using remember_me cookie
        }

        // do some other magic here
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        // ...
    }
}
```

my UserBundle.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: christianschade
 * Date: 24.01.15
 * Time: 15:10
 */

namespace Chris\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle {

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your service definition report the wrong namespace, missing the Controller path, try using the following configuration:

```
login_listener:
    class: 'Chris\UserBundle\Controller\LoginListener'
    arguments: ['@security.context', '@doctrine']
    tags:
    - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

Of course, i don't think this class is a **real** controller

Comment: thanks works ok, but how do i access the $this->getDoctrine() from LoginListener.php ?

Comment: You have injected in the constructor class, so can remove the line you cited in the comment and  simply use `$this->em->getRepository...`